# Variable next to method definition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, scope

I just started learning Ruby and am currently trying to figure out what this syntax means. It looks like a variable name ( *path* ) next to a method definition. It is not in parentheses, so it's not a parameter. Maybe a method-level variable?

```
def get_path path
   if clause
      @path = n
   else
      @path = m
   end
   return @path
end
```

No arguments are passed to this method.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Parenthesis are optional in Ruby. This:

```
def get_path path
end
```

Is the same as this:

```
def get_path(path)
end
```

Note that you may define one-liners with parenthesis as following:

```
def foo(a,b) puts (a*b).to_s end
```

But if you decide not to use parenthesis, you'll have to add a semicolon so Ruby knows where the args list ends. Calling a method can also be done with or without parenthesis:

```
def bar a,b; puts (a*b).to_s end
bar 2,3
#6
```

Comment: It might be an answer

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't have code that needs to use method result immediately,
>   Ruby allows to specify parameters omitting parentheses:

[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls)

That means:

```
get_path path
```

is equivalent to:

```
 get_path(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in method invocations as well as method definitions have optional parenthesis.

It is a convention that one should omit them when [invoking](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-args-no-parens)/[defining](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#method-parens) a method with no arguments or when invoking a method with the status of a keyword (even though this is a little fuzzy).

Omitting parenthesis when defining a method with arguments (as is the case here) is considered heavy offence, even though it's still a valid syntax.